# Printing a random amount of characters a random amount of times in one line

Tags: python

Let's assume we only have one line to work with. We have string "fo0", and we want to print each character a random amount of times, and redo that entire statement another random amount of times; Resulting in something like the following:

```
ffooooo000 ffffffoo00 fffo00000000
```

How does one go about doing this, using for loops or something similar?

As far as I've gotten:

```
import random; x = "fo0"; print "".join(x for i in range(0,random.randrange(0,40)))
```

All this results in is something like "`fo0fo0fo0fo0fo0fo0`".

Comment: why in one line? I mean, any specific reason?

Comment: I introduced an IRC channel to a bot that is able to run python scripts, but due to the nature of input in IRC you can only use one line, thus limiting your options to ternary operators and second-party hand loops. Someone suggested this as a challenge, and mainly I wanted to see if it was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like the following. Below, `s` is the input string, `char_rand_max` is the maximum number of times a single character is repeated in a word, and `str_rand_max` is the maximum number of times to produce a word. Each character appears at least once, and there is at least one word.

```
import random

def rand_print(s, char_rand_max, str_rand_max):
    for i in range(random.randint(1, str_rand_max)):
        print ''.join([c*random.randint(1, char_rand_max) for c in s]),
    print
```

Examples:

```
>>> s = 'fo0'
>>> rand_print(s, 5, 5)
fffoooo0000

>>> rand_print(s, 5, 5)
fo000 fffffooo00000 ffooo00000 fffooo00 fffo0

>>> rand_print(s, 5, 5)
ffffo00 fffffooo00000 fffffo00000
```

### One-line solution

You can, of course, do this all in one line, if you want. Rather than squashing the function from above into a single line, you can do the following:

```
from random import randint as ri; x = 'fo0'; \
    print ' '.join([''.join([c*ri(1, 5) for c in x]) for i in range(ri(1, 5))])
```

Note that I added a line break to make it more readable in the answer. Also, unlike the solution above, the maximum numbers of character repeats and words is hard-coded at five.

Comment: I wanted a solution that worked in one line! But thanks, this is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @CaptainLightning I missed the one-line requirement in the title. The question has been edited to add a one-line solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you are wanting, just call the method `x` number of times for `x` number of repetitions.

```
import random

def random_word(s, rand_range, rep):
     return " ".join("".join(ch*int(random.randrange(1,rand_range)) for ch in s) for _ in xrange(rep))


print random_word(x,5, 4)

Output: 
ffffoooo0000 ffffoooo000 fffooo000 fffoo00
```

the reason your method did not work is because you were just printing `"fo0"` out, `range(0,random.randrange(0,40)` number of times.

basically:

```
[x for i in range(0,10)]
```

is what you were doing, which will print out `x`, `range(0,10)` number of times.

Comment: The issue is that I was looking for a way to do it in only one line.

Comment: @CaptainLightning ahh i see, fixed for you.

Comment: @CaptainLightning forgot to mention, although it's in a method, you can pull it out for a one liner, but I prefer methods as they are more flexable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
"".join(x[random.randrange(0, len(x))] for i in xrange(0, random.randrange(0,40)))
```

Comment: This would work, but it scrambles the letters. The goal is to keep the letters in order while printing them a random amount of times.

Comment: @srgerg: I believe your code can be simplified to this: `"".join(random.choice(x) for i in xrange(random.randrange(40)))`. You should receive exact same effect.

Answer (score 1):

The `random` module has a function called `choice`.  You could use it like this:

```
import random as rand


def makeStr(chars, length):
    outs = ''
    for i in range(length):
        outs += rand.choice(chars)
    return outs


chars = ['f', 'o', '0']
length = 16

for i in range(0, 20):
    print makeStr(chars, length)
```

... and some example output:

> oofo0fof000oo00o 0fo0ff0foff0ofo0 ooooof0foffoo0oo 0fo0oofffoffo0fo
>   ofoo0oof0fo0oooo 0oooffo0fo0ofofo ff0off00ofo0ff0f 0fffooo0offoofo0
>   0f000oooffo0000o ff0ofo00f0ooooof f00ffff00oo0ffof o0oooo0oo00oooof
>   oooo0ff0of00ffof

EDIT: I may have misunderstood the problem.  If that output isn't what you were looking for, don't use my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to print between `0` and `N` times a randomly selected character in a set of characters, you'll want to perform a minor tweak to your code.

The culprit is:

```
"".join(x for i in range(0,random.randrange(0,40)))
```

which says "produce a random number of copies of `x` and concatenate them".

Perhaps what you want is this:

```
"".join(x[random.randrange(len(x))] for i in range(random.randrange(40))
```

which says "select a random number of random draws from `x` and concatenate them".